# The word, וּמִבַּלְעָדָיו, in the Hebrew translation of χωρὶς in John 1:3

Tags: greek, hebrew, john, new-testament

Hoping I can ask about a modern Hebrew translation.  I'm trying to understand the Hebrew word  **וּמִבַּלְעָדָיו** [from ha-Berit ha-ḥadashah. (2000). (John 1:3). Israel: The Bible Society in Israel. Delitzssch also uses this word] because it doesn't correspond to the Hebrew the LXX translates with χωρὶς (given in figure below). [image]

I recognize the beginning conjunction, followed by probably at least one preposition and the suffixed pronoun.  Here is the word withe the vowel points.  [image]  I found the word **בַּלְעָדָ** in the Peshitta.  So, that part appears to be the single word with the conjunction, preposition, and pronoun suffix attached.  I'm wondering if this word found in the Syriac translation is actually used in modern Hebrew.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I can see this chart in logos from the Greek in John 1:3 but where are you getting the Hebrew word?  What Bible verse is that from?  I can't replicate it in Logos

Comment: just looked it up in Delitzsch. Thanks for the heads up on that one!

Comment: What is the tool this screenshot is from?

Comment: It's the Bible Word Study Guide in Logos Bible Software.  You tell the the Bible you took the word from and then the Bible either translated from or to, resulting in the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

That helps!

it would read literally "and from apart/without/except him"

ו = and
מ = from
בלעדי = without or except
ו = him

it is used in Gen. 41:44 for the word "without"

> Then Pharaoh said to Joseph, "I am Pharaoh, but **without** your word no one will lift hand or foot in all Egypt."

Hope that helps you along your journey!!

Comment: looking at more lexicons, found it here: 1187 בַּלְעֲדֵי (bǎl·ʿǎḏê): prep.; ≡ Str 1107; TWOT 246h—1. LN 89.120–89.122 apart from, except for, not, i.e., a marker of dissociation (Isa 44:6); 2. LN 89.92–89.104 besides, i.e., a marker of an addition (Nu 5:20)

Swanson, J. (1997). Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains : Hebrew (Old Testament) (electronic ed.). Oak Harbor: Logos Research Systems, Inc.

Comment: I did the chart with χωρὶς and the words in the LXX to translate it to verify it wasn't translated with χωρὶς.  Interesting that there is no overlap between the Hebrew OT and LXX.  Also interesting that the Peshitta used ܘܒ݂ܶܠܥܳܕ݂ܰܘܗ̄ܝ̈ in John 1:3.

Comment: Now I know the addition tools needed.  Glad to know it wasn't as difficult as I thought.